# Separar elementos en un navbar de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Estoy trabajando una web usando Bootstrap y necesito ayuda para separar los elementos de un `navbar`, de forma tal que el logo se ubique a la derecha y las secciones a la izquierda de la página.

Intenté colocando la propiedad `d-flex justify-content-between` entre ambos elementos pero al parecer no tiene ningún efecto. Así mismo, intenté colocando un `span` vacío en medio asignándole un margen en `%` para que no afecte la versión *responsive*, sin embargo tampoco funcionó.

¿Algún consejo sobre cómo lograr esa separación sin que afecte la versión *responsive*?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Resultado obtenido actualmente]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Aclarar que subir capturas del codigo no es bien visto por la comunidad, edita la pregunta, copia y pega tu codigo como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto como se han de crear navs en boostrap

[Ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)

[Más información](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

EDIT:

Adjunto un ejemplo de código.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, de seguro que los enlaces que dejas pueden ayudar a su problema, pero los enlaces facilmente se rompen o pierden con el tiempo. De paso leete [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que se bien vista por la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias. ya esta arreglado

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear dos listas en tu navbar, la primera con la clase **"ml-auto"** para que se ponga del lado izquierdo y la segunda lista con la clase **"mr-auto"** para que se quede del lado derecho.

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logo</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```